# Matching different/multiple parts of a Makefile target

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, target

Here is a Makefile that I currently use to make targets with different configurations, i.e., I am building different software packages with the same target, either all at once or individually.

```
.PHONY: build test %.build %.test build-all test-all
%.build %.test: PACKAGE = $*

%.build:
    @echo build $(PACKAGE)

%.test:
    @echo test $(PACKAGE)

build-all: a.build b.build
test-all:  a.test  b.test

build: $(PACKAGE).build
test:  $(PACKAGE).test
```

I can now build all packages with `make build-all` or individual packages with, e.g., `make build PACKAGE=a`. However I would like to switch the body of the `%.build` and `build`, etc. targets as in the following:

```
.PHONY: build test %.build %.test build-all test-all
build:
    @echo build $(PACKAGE)

test:
    @echo test $(PACKAGE)

build-all: a.build b.build
test-all:  a.test  b.test

%.build %.test: PACKAGE = $*
$(PACKAGE).%: $*
```

This way, the pattern matching logic is fully separated from the "main" targets `build` and `test` that should contain the actual build commands; making the important parts of the Makefile more readable. However, the last line does not work as intended, i.e., running `make a.build` and thus `make build-all` should trigger the target `build` with `PACKAGE=a`. The variable assignment in second-last line works, the target matching in the last line does not.

**Question:** Is there a way to express a matching target like `$(PACKAGE).%: $*` or to match separate parts of a target like `%.%: $2`?

Comment: I realize this is just an example, but there's nothing here that requires make. If this really is all there is to it then you're using the wrong tool, just write a shell script. As the first sentence on the [make homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) points out, "GNU Make is a tool which controls the **generation of executables and other non-source files of a program from the program's source files.**"

Comment: I use this pattern to build and test executables from go code, e.g., calling `go build` or `go install`, and `go test` for packages in different subdirs. I also use this pattern to build executables inside docker images and to build the docker images themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you probably want:

```
$(PACKAGE).% : %
```

not using `$*`, which is an automatic variable and so it has no value except inside the recipe; you can't use it like that in the prerequisite lists.

Second, you can't do this in GNU make.  A pattern rule with no recipe doesn't just a create prerequisite relationship, like an explicit rule would do; instead it *deletes the pattern rule*.  Since you didn't have a pattern rule for `$(PACKAGE).%` yet, this is basically a no-op.  Also, target-specific variables are only available inside the recipe, so trying to use `$(PACKAGE)` in the target definition and expecting it to take the value from some previously set target-specific variable cannot work.

You could do something like this, but it's not fully dynamic (you still need the list of packages and types):

```
PACKAGES = a b
TYPES = build test

$(foreach T,$(TYPES),$(eval $(addsuffix .$T,$(PACKAGES)): $T))
```

Comment: OK, so I need `foreach` and `eval`. I wanted avoid that. Nevertheless, this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As MadScientist explained, the problem cannot be solved easily in GNU make. For completeness, I would like to add and explain my final and more comprehensive solution:

```
.PHONY: all build test clean %.build %.test build-all test-all

PACKAGES  = a b c e f g
PACKAGE   = a

all: clean build-all test-all

%.build %.test: PACKAGE = $*

%.build:
    @echo build $(PACKAGE)

%.test:
    @echo test $(PACKAGE)

clean:
    @echo remove build dir

build-all: $(addsuffix .build, $(PACKAGES))
test-all:  $(addsuffix .test,  $(PACKAGES))

build: $(PACKAGE).build
test:  $(PACKAGE).test
```

This solution avoids `eval` and `foreach` and is based on my initial working solution, where the dynamic `%.build` and `%.test` targets contain the actual build commands. I added the `PACKAGES` variable to facilitate easy addition of new packages, a default `PACKAGE` to prevent execution of misconfigured build commands, and the common targets `all` and `clean` as complements.

From the command line, you just call `make` `all`, `clean`, `build PACKAGE=x`, `build-all`, etc., i.e., only the static targets, which will then trigger the build commands in the dynamic targets. The static targets and the two variables are also visible in the Bash/Zsh auto-completion.

I think this is the most flexible and yet readable way to build multiple dynamic targets.

Comment: If you only have two target types (`build` and `test`) then writing them out is definitely simpler and more readable.